# Python script running multiple times when I put it in /etc/network/if-up.d/?

Tags: python, email, networking, smtp, ubuntu-16.04

I made a python script which sends mails to a given id using SMTP server .I wanted the script to run everytime I connect to the internet ,so I put myfile (say python.py) in location "/etc/network/if-up.d/" without the extension in it and made it executable by "sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-up.d/python" command. Everything worked fine i.e my script ran when I connected to internet but then I noticed that the email-id to which mails were sent received multiple mails(mostly twice), that means the script ran several times. Why is to so?Does the script kept in "if-up.d/"  run many times or its related to my network.(Note: my network(usb-tethered) was not disconnected during the process and I have used similar script to run after boot using crontab,it ran fine. And I am workin on Ubutu 16.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question but I ran into a similar issue. My post can be viewed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1098775/if-up-d-launches-two-instances-of-a-single-script/) but if-up.d/ does not guarantee a script will run only once. What it does is it takes the script and executes it on a per interface basis (one execution for `eth0`, one for `wlan0`, one for `lo`, etc). If the script is meant to be run only once, two options to get the desired effect are:

***My initial approach*** 
at the script level, if you're running something continuous, you could check to make sure only one instance of your script is running. I was running a python bot for our IRC server that connected twice because of this and I wrote this to resolve it

```
def check_running():
    get_processes = 'ps aux'.split()             # grab list of running processes
    get_bots      = 'grep bot.py$ -c'.split()    # search for your script, note the '$' for an end of line match and '-c' for a numeric count of occurrences
    out1          = subprocess.Popen(get_processes, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out2          = int(subprocess.check_output(get_bots, stdin=out1.stdout).rstrip())
    return        out2


if check_running() != 1: # the count should be one since the script is looking for itself
    sys.exit(0)
                         # continue with the script after performing initial check
```

***The Accurate Approach***
I wrapped my call to python in a sh script and the sh script is what's stored in `if-up.d/`. All I'd need to do for this approach is update my script to verify the interface I'd like to use before executing the call.

```
[ "$IFACE" = 'eth0' ] || exit 0 # interface accessing script must match, or exit
sleep 269 
sh -c "python /dir/to/bot.py >> /dir/to/log" & disown
```